# Why is LinkedListNode class immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list

I am curious to know why all the properties(Next, Previous, Value etc) exposed by the LinkedListNode class are readonly i.e. these properties are not having their corresponding setters?

I was trying to solve a small linked list related algorithmic problem and decided to use .Net's built in LinkedList class. But due to readonly behavior of LinkedListNode's class properties, I cannot override the values or change the "Next" pointer of any given node.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to change the `Value` property, even though the documentation doesn't suggest that `Value` is settable

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: It shows it is settable: http://marker.to/2iMfJ5   The summary description of the property is misleading though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Value` does have a setter, the declaration is [`public T Value { get; set; }`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86397t7k.aspx).

The lack of setters on `Next` and `Previous` prevent you from turning the linked list into a tree or other topology that the `LinkedList` methods aren't designed to cope with.

> [The LinkedList class does not support chaining, splitting, cycles, or other features that can leave the list in an inconsistent state.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)

You can change these properties by using the list's methods such as `AddBefore` that preserve the invariants that each `LinkedListNode` is a member of only one list, `node.Next.Previous` always points back to `node`, and there are no cycles, etc.

Comment: That might be a reason why you can't change `Next` or `Previous` properties. Changing the value won't change the list onto a tree.

Answer (score 2):

`Next`/`Previous` are readonly to make sure that you won't mess up the list structure. You have to use `LinkedList<T>` methods to modify the list, and they will make sure you won't end up with incorrect state. Letting you change the references would make it possible.

Even though [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx), that `Value` is not settable, if you look at [`LinkedListNode<T>`  source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs#ab8931f084807c6d#references), you'll find that there is actually a setter defined!

```
// Note following class is not serializable since we customized the serialization of LinkedList. 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)] 
public sealed class LinkedListNode<T> {
    internal LinkedList<T> list;
    internal LinkedListNode<T> next;
    internal LinkedListNode<T> prev;
    internal T item;

    public LinkedListNode( T value) {
        this.item = value;
    }

    internal LinkedListNode(LinkedList<T> list, T value) {
        this.list = list;
        this.item = value;
    }

    public LinkedList<T> List {
        get { return list;}
    }

    public LinkedListNode<T> Next {
        get { return next == null || next == list.head? null: next;}
    }

    public LinkedListNode<T> Previous {
        get { return prev == null || this == list.head? null: prev;}
    }

    public T Value {
        get { return item;}
        set { item = value;}
    }

    internal void Invalidate() {
        list = null;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }           
}
```

So you should be able to change the value.

Comment: Oh, that's inconsistent with `LinkedListNode(T)` page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx. Should be `Gets or sets the value contained in the node`.

Comment: There are may places where the documentation is inconsistent with what is implemented (particularly around properties and their getters and setters). This is just one of those cases.